# search in a text field which contains json

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json

My Application is in `RoR` and DB is in `MYSQL`. I have  a `User Table`. It contains a field `name`. Its type is text.
It contains the value like `{"first_name"=> 'Allen', "last_name"=> 'PAul'}` and some other information.

I am able to store the same in DB by using `store: accessors: [], coder: JSON`.

**Now, I want to retrive all records whose first_name == 'Allen'**. So how to achieve this in rails

Comment: User.where(:first_name => 'Allen') ?

Comment: no, it will not work

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column

Comment: how you are storing `name` value using `{first_name: 'Allen', last_name: 'PAul'}` ? are you defined a custom method inside model to add both as name?

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy: write this in model store :name, accessors: [ :first_name, :last_name], coder: JSON

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma updated answer. Please try and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works

```
User.where("name LIKE ?", , '%first_name: #{query}%')
```

Comment: it works but need to remove the space after first_name:

Comment: also, add the quotes like "first_name":"Allen"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to search in JSON fields with classic ActiveRecord.

But you can execute raw sql:

edit: Your name field must be a json field.

```
@users = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE JSON_SEARCH(name, 'all', '#{first_name_to_search}') IS NOT NULL;")
```

more info [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/)

Comment: JSON Search does not exists, I think it only works when we have json datatype in db

Answer (score 1):

Problem is the actual textual representation that is used to represent the json...

Using

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
```

you can see how the LIKE clause should be structured to find the actual textual representation in the database. Afterwards you can use

```
User.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE ...")
```

to do the actual query

Answer (score 0):

You have overloaded the `name` field using [`ActiveRecord::Store`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html). From the documentation:

> Store gives you a thin wrapper around serialize for the purpose of storing hashes in a single column. It's like a simple key/value store baked into your record **when you don't care about being able to query that store** outside the context of a single record.

You cannot use the field in the manner that you are describing, and attempting to do so goes against the purpose of the API you're using, so I would advise against it. You have several options:

1. Search the field using some type of slow query (`SELECT * FROM User WHERE name LIKE '%foo%'`)
2. Instantiate all the records, then parse them (`User.all.map { |user| user.name.match(/foo/)`)
3. Normalize your database and assign proper fields for each field you want to search by (`name` splits into `first_name` and `last_name`)

Of these three options, only **3** is the right thing to do. The other two may work but should not be used because of the performance and reliability issues it will introduce.

As a bonus to using **3**, you can create a method to fulfill the role of `name`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name
    {
      first_name: first_name,
      last_name: last_name
    }
  end
end
```

You can then search the way you want:

```
user = User.where(first_name: 'foo').first
```

And still return the name:

```
user.name
=> { first_name: 'foo', last_name: 'bar' }
```